# Шифрование RSA в vbscript

Tags: com, rsa, vbscript, aes

В **VBScript** есть встроенный **com объект** для работы с **AES** шифрованием - **System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged**

*Для этого правда требуется net framework 3.5.*

Но я не нашёл нигде информации: **есть ли в VBScript поддержка шифрования RSA?**

Comment: Стандартная библиотека .NET общая для всех языков, и RSA в ней тоже есть https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa?view=netframework-3.5

Comment: @andreymal _жаль что вы ответили ради ответа, а не истины. Потому что ваш ответ **не ответ** на поставленный вопрос._ При регистрации в скрипте **set obj=WScript.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.AsymmetricAlgorithm")** пишет, что **не удалось найти класс программируемых объектов** Я же спросил: **есть ли COM объект RSA в VBScript?**

Comment: Во-первых, я не ответил, а оставил комментарий. Во-вторых, `set obj=WScript.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider")` замечательно работает, а зачем вы попытались получить абстрактный класс, я не знаю

Comment: Соответственно `encrypted = obj.Encrypt((bytes), false)` и `decrypted = obj.Decrypt((encrypted), false)` по аналогии с AES тоже работают (но на специалиста по VBScript я не тяну, так что писать полноценный ответ не стану)

Comment: @andreymal да, действительно работает, правда пока не совсем понятно, как в генерации ключей установить длину ключа в 4096 байт: `xmlPriPubKey = obj.ToXmlString(True)
xmlPubKey = obj.ToXmlString(False)`
и почему при выводе ключей `WScript.Echo xmlPubKey` `WScript.Echo xmlPriPubKey` они не в стандартном виде типа _-----begin-privat-key-----_